# PC is configured properly but .jar files still won't run

Tags: java, windows, executable-jar

When I make a .jar file using BlueJ, it runs fine on both of my PCs (Notebooks)-one is running Windows Vista the other Windows 7 -but not on a different PC running Windows XP. This third PC does have the correct file association and a JRE. No error is displayed, the critical stop sound plays but there is no other activity.

The real question here is why did a standalone JRE work in Windows 7 but not Windows XP?

How can I be sure that people I write programs for can run the jar file without having to install a JDK? A JRE was sufficient for my Windows 7 pc, why is this not always the case?

Comment: I guess it's not *really* configured properly then...

Comment: What is it that's wrong? As aforementioned there is no error message.

Comment: All the other help I've found online indicates how to make the file associations, which I have done. The PC in question can run Java content on websites.

Comment: Can you run the .JAR file manually? E.g. `C:\...\javaw -jar my.jar`?

Comment: No, same result (or lack thereof) as double clicking the icon.

Comment: Can you run *other* Java programs? e.g. Azure or Eclipse or Open Office?

Comment: I installed BlueJ and a JDK to test what you asked and now the problem is solved! How is the JRE included with the JDK different from a standalone JRE? I had a standalone JRE on the Windows 7 PC before installing BlueJ and had no problems with .jar files.

Comment: You can do some verifications: Check that the .JAR file is ok (JAR is only a ZIP, you can open it with WinZip or other tool to check the contents); Check if the Java version (`java -version`) is the same; run it with `java -verbose` .

Comment: @MattB No idea :-) Glad your problem is solved now. Write an "answer/solution" (to yourself) and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

if  more than one  jdk  is installed,you must remove its.Then you  install  lastest version of jdk.

Comment: There is only one jdk on the computer in question. There was, however a standalone jre installed _before_ the jdk was installed. This same standalone jre (if not an older one) would run jar files (by double clicking) on the windows vista pc.

Comment: I meant windows 7 pc not windows vista

Answer (score 0):

A standalone JRE allowed excution of jar files by double clicking on Windows 7 but not Windows XP. Based on this, some JREs perform differently than others on different O/Ss.